# ILOG context IBM

Tags: ilog

I am new to ILOG and I want to know, what does this statement mean:

```
IlrContext() from ?context;
```

I do not see "context" defined as variable in a sample project in my work space. Is this an implicit variable that is defined in ILOG?

Comment: In Ilog JRules, the ilrContext is the context of rule and rulesets execution. This is where all data will be found/written by the engine. There are many ways to call a rules engine, where do you see this statement ?

Comment: I see it in one of the .trl file and in the "when" condition

Comment: I can't check tonight as I don't have my JRules project with me but I think this is the context you provided to the engine. I don't see what  this line could be useful to, though.

Answer (score 1):

`IlrContext` is the base class of all the execution contexts. Rules can be executed only within an execution context.

An `IlrContext` instance provide all context data to the engine (`rulesets`, `variables`, `parameters` etc.)

[IlrContext Class](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/brjrules/v7r0m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.ilog.jrules.doc/html/api/html/ilog/rules/engine/IlrContext.html)